# Node.js is not running in Docker is my docker-compose.yml correct?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

### The problem:

I'm trying to set up a Docker WordPress development environment on Windows 11 with wsl2. I created a docker-compose.yml and everything works apart from the node install. The container tries to start it and then just stops. Is something in my docker-compose file wrong?

I want to use node because I use gulp, npm and browser sync for my WordPress themes.

### This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
  node:
    restart: "no"
    image: node:latest
    container_name: nodejs
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    volumes:
      - node-data:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
volumes:
  dbdata:
  wp-content:
  node-data:
```

Comment: I've generally found a great tool for working on Node code is Node itself; there's not really value in trying to set up Docker to run Node to actually run code on your host.  The Compose setup you show doesn't really do anything and the `node` container will just exit immediately without doing anything; you can't invoke it from the host, it's in an isolated container and can't see your source files, _etc._

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So but how would I get the node functionality while using docker with WordPress? Or is docker just not a useful tool in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Dockerfile otherwise it will never ever work!

Comment: Oh really? Thanks I didn't know that! I will try it out.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have mentioned to spin up the docker container but just think for a sec how will you command node to tell that what it needs to do .When it sees no action commanded it basically closes up .

**Solution**

1. Long way - You can use up a dockerfile, as mentioned by Tom , dockerfile is generally used to containerise your application so whatever code you need do just write it , then build your code into a docker image with node using Dockerfile , but in that case trouble is that everytime you are doing any code change you have reiterate over the same process and again build your code.
2. Another simple way I could think of is add a `command:npm start` in your node image and this should help you probably

Forgive me if I have suggested something wrong because I am also learner in docker :)